# using curl commands in php

Tags: php, command-line, curl

I've been stumped on how to use curl in php, for running this piece of code.

```
  $ curl -F userfile=@Image_File_Name \
     -F outputencoding="utf-8" \
     -F outputformat="txt" \
     http://Server_Address/cgi-bin/submit.cgi >result.txt
```

Could anyone help me? I've tried the following:

```
$cmd="curl -F userfile=$file_new \ 
      -F outputencoding="utf-8" \
      F outputformat=txt \ 
      http://maggie.ocrgrid.org/cgi-bin/weocr/ocr_scene.cgi >result.txt"
exec($cmd,$result);
echo $result;
```

but it does not work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your double quotes that are in the string:

```
$cmd="curl -F userfile=$file_new \ 
      -F outputencoding=\"utf-8\" \
      F outputformat=\"txt\" \ 
      http://maggie.ocrgrid.org/cgi-bin/weocr/ocr_scene.cgi >result.txt"
```

That should work. [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) also returns it's output in an array separated by newlines. So `echo $result;` will just print 'Array'. You may want to echo $result[0]; or consider using [`backticks`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php) or [`passthru`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php).

Rather than executing the cURL in a separate shell though, I recommend the php cURL library: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Answer (score 0):

[libcurl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) will suit you better - it provides all the functions and error handling you'll need for using cURL in PHP.